# "error: cannot access Killable" while compiling the code with selenium java 3.11 libraries

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

The code compilation is failing with "error: cannot access Killable" at the line 
class FirefoxWebDriver extends FirefoxDriver{
......

We have upgraded to Selenium 3.11 from 3.3.1. We are trying to run tests on browser configured with selenium grid using Docker. I found that Killable class was removed. Kindly suggest if I need update any code chagnes.

Thanks.

Comment: `at the line class FirefoxWebDriver extends FirefoxDriver` and `tests on chrome browser` ... can you cross check?

Comment: we have code for each driver (chrome, firefox). The code compilation is failing at Firefox driver while running the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tough to analyze/conclude without your *Project Setup* information (i.e. you are using *Selenium JARs*, *Ant*, *Maven* or *Gradle*), your *code trials* and the *error stack trace*.

However this error message...

```
error: cannot access Killable
```

...implies that your program faced an error while while accessing **Killable**.

### Killable.class file

As per the discussion [**Killable ClassNotFound**](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/selenium-developers/ojInlWRmeZw) the **Killable.class** file was contained in [**selenium-api-2.21.0.jar**](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-api/2.21.0/selenium-api-2.21.0.jar). Additionally, using *Maven dependency of selenium-server 2.21.0* produced the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/internal/Killable
```

### Explaination

As you have mentioned you have upgraded from *Selenium 3.3.1* to *Selenium 3.11* the possible reason is **version conflict** among the binaries you are using either in the form of *JARs*, *Maven* or *Gradle* dependency and can be due to **presence** of one/multiple among the following:

- **selenium-server 2.21.0.jar**
- **selenium-api-2.21.0.jar**
- **Maven dependency** of *selenium-server 2.21.0* or *selenium-api-2.21.0*
- **Gradle dependency** of *selenium-server 2.21.0* or *selenium-api-2.21.0*

### Solution

- If you are using *Selenium Java Jars* download and add the respective jar/jars either (from):

  - **selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar**
  - **selenium-java-3.11.0.zip**
- If you are using *Maven dependency for Selenium* use either of the following:

  - *Selenium Java Client dependency*:

    ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
  - *Selenium Server dependency*:

    ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ```

### trivia

If you are using *Maven* you can add this block in your **root pom** (within the build section just add to the plugins) to troubleshoot the different versions of binaries you got.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enforce</id>
            <goals>
            <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <rules>
                <DependencyConvergence />
            </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For your reference **selenium-server 2.21.0** output tree was as follows:

```
[INFO] \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.47:compile
[INFO]    +- mx4j:mx4j-tools:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.9:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:jetty-repacked:jar:7.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-android-driver:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.json:json:jar:20080701:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |        \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.15:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:platform:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-iphone-driver:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:2.21.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.webbitserver:webbit:jar:0.4.6:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.7.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
```

Comment: The issue is resolved and as you mentioned, there are references still pointing to old version of selenium. By cleaning up those references, we are not seeing errors now.